# Fieldset disabled

Tags: html, css

I have big form which is divided by tabs, for some roles(under admin rights) i give them to see form but i don't allow them to change anything so when users with that admin rights are logged i set fieldset disabled. Problem is my tabs are locked too so they can only see first tab and cant click on other tabs..

I need a way to enable only tabs inside fieldset which is disabled.

I can manually set each fields to disabled / enabled with the help of JS but i am looking to use less code possible so if it is possible with css it would be good.. ?

I tried setting tabs only with disabled="false" (null, everything i came up to but its not working)

Comment: post your codes, so we can help you

Comment: You dont need code, question is simple, when you set fieldset disabled is there a way to enable some of fields ?

Comment: are you adding any class to disable tab?
Try $("selector").tabs("enable", n); where n is the index of the tab

Comment: Is this a CMS? If so which one?

Comment: Nope it is application, i am doing backend, design is finished but i do small changes on frontend.. It is really big app, and i need to handle this.. If i dont find solution i will have to disable each field and not fieldset so i can have tabs enabled and working...

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you have html along these lines:

```
<fieldset disabled class="bunch-a-tabs">
  <ul class="tabs">
    <li class="tab tab-control" href="#tab1">Tab 1</li>
    <li class="tab tab-control" href="#tab2">Tab 2</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab tab-content" id="tab1">
     <!-- tab 1 content -->
  </div>
  <div class="tab tab-content" id="tab2">
     <!-- tab 2 content -->
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

.. and while you do want the contents of each tab to be disabled from interaction you do however want the tab-controls to be active.

**Could you instead wrap the contents of each tab with fieldset?**

```
<div class="bunch-a-tabs">
  <ul class="tabs">
    <li class="tab tab-control" href="#tab1">Tab 1</li>
    <li class="tab tab-control" href="#tab2">Tab 2</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab tab-content" id="tab1">
    <fieldset disabled>
      <!-- tab 1 content -->
    </fieldset>
  </div>
  <div class="tab tab-content" id="tab2">
    <fieldset disabled>
      <!-- tab 2 content -->
    </fieldset>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You should remove disabled attribute and make "a" tag not clickable.

pointer-events: none will do the trick

```
    HTML

    <fieldset>


    <div id="tabs">
      <ul>
        <li><a id="one" href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
        <li><a id="two" href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
        <li><a id="three" href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
     </ul>
       <div id="tabs-1">
          <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus.    Curabitur nec arcu. Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris. Nam elementum quam ullamcorper ante. Etiam aliquet massa et lorem. Mauris dapibus lacus auctor risus. Aenean tempor ullamcorper leo. Vivamus sed magna quis ligula eleifend adipiscing. Duis orci. Aliquam sodales tortor vitae ipsum. Aliquam nulla. Duis aliquam molestie erat. Ut et mauris vel pede varius sollicitudin. Sed ut dolor nec orci tincidunt interdum. Phasellus ipsum. Nunc tristique tempus lectus.</p>
     </div>
        <div id="tabs-2">
          <p>Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet facilisis feugiat, odio metus gravida ante, ut pharetra massa metus id nunc. Duis scelerisque molestie turpis. Sed fringilla, massa eget luctus malesuada, metus eros molestie lectus, ut tempus eros massa ut dolor. Aenean aliquet fringilla sem. Suspendisse sed ligula in ligula suscipit aliquam. Praesent in eros vestibulum mi adipiscing adipiscing. Morbi facilisis. Curabitur ornare consequat nunc. Aenean vel metus. Ut posuere viverra nulla. Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque convallis. Maecenas feugiat, tellus pellentesque pretium posuere, felis lorem euismod felis, eu ornare leo nisi vel felis. Mauris consectetur tortor et purus.</p>
      </div>
        <div id="tabs-3">
         <p>Mauris eleifend est et turpis. Duis id erat. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam vulputate, pede vel vehicula accumsan, mi neque rutrum erat, eu congue orci lorem eget lorem. Vestibulum non ante. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Fusce sodales. Quisque eu urna vel enim commodo pellentesque. Praesent eu risus hendrerit ligula tempus pretium. Curabitur lorem enim, pretium nec, feugiat nec, luctus a, lacus.</p>
         <p>Duis cursus. Maecenas ligula eros, blandit nec, pharetra at, semper at, magna. Nullam ac lacus. Nulla facilisi. Praesent viverra justo vitae neque. Praesent blandit adipiscing velit. Suspendisse potenti. Donec mattis, pede vel pharetra blandit, magna ligula faucibus eros, id euismod lacus dolor eget odio. Nam scelerisque. Donec non libero sed nulla mattis commodo. Ut sagittis. Donec nisi lectus, feugiat porttitor, tempor ac, tempor vitae, pede. Aenean vehicula velit eu tellus interdum rutrum. Maecenas commodo. Pellentesque nec elit. Fusce in lacus. Vivamus a libero vitae lectus hendrerit hendrerit.</p>
      </div>
       </div>
   </fieldset>



   JAVASCRIPT

  $(function() {
       $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
     });
```